# Finding a case when binary search fails

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve a really interesting programming challenge and I'm sort of out of the ideas why my code fails. Here it is:

> Write a function that, given a list and a target sum, returns
> zero-based indices of any two distinct elements whose sum is equal to
> the target sum. If there are no such elements, the function should
> return null.
> For example, findTwoSum(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12) should return any of the following tuples of indices:
>
> ```
> 1, 4 (3 + 9 = 12)
> 2, 3 (5 + 7 = 12)
> 3, 2 (7 + 5 = 12)
> 4, 1 (9 + 3 = 12)
> ```

Should be simple right? So here's my function:

```
public static int[] findTwoSum(int[] list, int sum) {
        int[] indices = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            int currentNum = list[i];
            int findNum = sum - currentNum;
            int length = list.length;
            int min = i;
            int max = length-1;
                        
            while(max >= min) {
                int guess = (max+min)/2;
                          
                if(list[guess] == findNum) {
                  return new int[] {i,guess};
                } 
                
                if(list[guess] < findNum) {
                    min = guess + 1;
                }
                
                if(list[guess] > findNum) {
                    max = guess - 1;
                }
            }
            
        }
       
        
        return indices;
    }
```

Code is pretty simple,  for every element in the array, it tries to find using binary search, another element, so that their sum is equal to the provided `sum`. I've tested this code and I couldn't find scenario where it fails, assuming that the provided array is sorted. However, when I run this code on [TestDome](https://www.testdome.com/Questions/Java/TwoSum/5350?testId=27&testDifficulty=Easy) , the last case fails, it is somehow wrong solution. Could anybody point out what is wrong with this approach ?

Comment: The question asks for two _distinct_ elements of a list, which your code does not seem to handle properly.

Comment: @Gassa Yeah, I had a check for that too, it didn't help really. What I'm now thinking is, that it could be that the array is not sorted in the last case.

Comment: Is the given list already in sorted form?

Comment: @User_Targaryen I expected it to be, but I could be wrong. So I guess I need to sort it first and keep track of the original indexes.

Comment: @Zed: Definitely that's the problem then....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code assumes that the list is sorted. The problem statement does not say anything about the order of elements, so you need to sort the array yourself. Since you need indexes, you need to sort pairs of values and indexes.

A faster approach is to put the data into a hash map with counts and original indexes, and check for presence of `Target - n` for each `n` in the list. You need counts for the special case when `Target` is equal to `2*n`.

Comment: (`A faster approach` _than searching for the difference between a chosen number and the target sum_) A _simpler_ approach would (binary) search just for the difference from the first number and walk two indices starting up from the first and down from the one found until they meet (unique pairs) or reach the other's start (problem as stated/this part is [Targaryen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40679675/3789665)).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question and clarification from the author regarding the sorted order of the initial list, it seems that the initial list is not sorted. So the list needs to be sorted and the original indices need to be stored separately in another list.

After sorting the array and keeping note of the original indices, let us say that `arr[]` contains the sorted list and `indices[]` contains the original indices of the corresponding elements in `arr[]`. In simpler words, `indices[i]` gives the original index of the element `arr[i]`.

Now you can follow the 2-SUM algorithm for finding the pair:

- Initialize two index variables to find the candidate 
  elements in the sorted array.

  - Initialize first to the leftmost index: l = 0
  - Initialize second  the rightmost index:  r = ar_size-1
- Loop while l < r.

  - If (arr[l] + arr[r] == sum)  then return pair(indices[l],indices[r])
  - Else if( arr[l] + arr[r] <  sum )  then l++
  - Else r--
- No candidates in whole array - return `NULL`

You can also use your binary search technique instead of the 2-SUM procedure.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It sorts the array and uses a binary search to locate the second element, which must be *sum - n*.

If a matching pair is found, it is looked up in the original array to determine the original index:

```
public static int[] findTwoSum(int[] list, int sum) {
    int len = list.length;
    int[] sortedList= Arrays.copyOf(list, len);
    Arrays.sort(sortedList);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int m = list[i];
        int j = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedList, sum - m);
        if (j >= 0 && i != j)
            return new int[] { i, findIndex(list, sortedList[j]) };
    }
    return null;
}

public static int findIndex(int[] list, int m) {
    int len = list.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (list[i] == m)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```